# Selecting containers with same class name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I click on element, the 'panel' element gets `style.display` property added to it.

It works fine, but since there are multiple 'panel' elements, I would like to have the code set up in a way that when one of the 'panel' elements get the `display = block` added, the other elements with the same class name would get `display = none`.

The most straightforward way for me sounds to find all elements with the same class('panel') and have them under a variable siblings or something similar. when one element gets `display = block` added, the siblings would get `display = none`.

That way only one element would be visible at a time, which is what I want. Any suggestions.? Thank you.

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How would click other elements when they are hidden?

Comment: It's the content that's getting hidden not the elements you click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to give all the panel elements a common class and then set display to none for all of them before you set display to block on the specific panel...

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            hideAllPanels();
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}

function hideAllPanels() {
    // This next line needs the class name you add to the panels
    var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel"); 

    for (var i = 0, l = panels.length; i < l; i++) {
        panels[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this works great.! Wish I was able to come up with the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use CSS instead of JS for this:

CSS

```
.panel { display:none; }
.active+.panel { display:block; }
```

The CSS selector `+` means next sibling, which is exactly what you need. You'll need to add the `panel` class to your panel elements.

JS

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector(".active") && document.querySelector(".active").classList.toggle("active"); // deactivate previously activated
        this.classList.toggle("active"); // activate current
    });
}
```

Note that there's no need to change the `display` directly, the CSS selectors will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this https://jsfiddle.net/vjcn8rom/4/

```
acc = document.getElementsByClassName("panel")
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var result = [], node = this.parentNode.firstChild;
    this.style.display = 'block';
    while( node != null ) {
      node = node.nextElementSibling || node.nextSibling
      if(node && node.style && node != this)
        node.style.display = 'none'
    }
    })
}
```